# How to customize a horizontal stacked-bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm just starting with R visuals, and I'm stuck on this one. In the code below you will find the table I'm working with and its rendering.

What I'm trying to do is to obtain a horizontal bar chart where for each Pool value I have two variables (D_MTD and I_MTD).

To achieve that (and I don't know if this is the right way of doing it) I added two geom_bar layers and what I get is pretty much what it should look like (it's okay to have stacked columns).

```
MyTable <- data.frame(
             Pool = c(" ", "(CA) Domestic", "(CA) International", "(FR) International", "(US) Domestic", "(US) International" ), 
             ADomestic = c(0, 36000, 3000, 1200, 54000, 6000), 
             AInternational = c(0, 0, 600, 600, 0, 1200), 
             D_MTD = c(23.4, 0, 0, 0, 8.38, 0),
             I_MTD = c(6.63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

MyTable


MyVisual <- MyTable %>% 
             ggplot(
                    Data = MyTable, 
                    aes(y = Pool)
                    ) + 
             geom_bar(
                    aes(
                        weight = D_MTD, 
                        colour = "Domestic"
                       ), 
                     alpha = 0.5
                     ) +
             geom_bar(
                    aes( 
                       weight = I_MTD, 
                       colour = "International"
                    ), 
                     alpha = 0.5
                    ) + 
              labs(
                   title = "Month-To-Date Consumption by Pool", 
                   subtitle = "(in minutes)", 
                   y = "Pools", 
                   x = "MTD Used Minutes", 
                   colour = "Pool context"
               )

MyVisual
```

[image: Visual as is]

However, the visual has two outline colours that I don't want (I would like the bars to be filled with colors instead). I tried to use the fill argument to assign a fixed color to the bars (ex: red for Domestic and blue for International) but that generates another legend that I don't want to show.

Example:

```
MyVisual <- MyTable %>% 
             ggplot(
                    Data = MyTable, 
                    aes(y = Pool)
                    ) + 
             geom_bar(
                    aes(
                        weight = D_MTD, 
                        colour = "Domestic", 
                        fill = "red"
                       ), 
                     alpha = 0.5
                     ) +
             geom_bar(
                    aes( 
                       weight = I_MTD, 
                       colour = "International", 
                       fill = "blue"
                    ), 
                     alpha = 0.5
                    ) + 
              labs(
                   title = "Month-To-Date Consumption by Pool", 
                   subtitle = "(in minutes)", 
                   y = "Pools", 
                   x = "MTD Used Minutes", 
                   colour = "Pool context"
               )

MyVisual
```

[image: Visual with fill argument]

Also, how do I apply labels to each bar with the corresponding values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it true that you're not using `ADomestic` and `AInternational` columns in this graph?

Comment: He is not, I think.

Comment: Hi @DanAdams, no, I'm not using them at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work for you. It contains elements, and transformation that for a starter may be confusing, but you will have to face these at some point. I recommend you to read the book R for Data Science, at least the chapter reated to data visualization with ggplot2.

**Steps:**

1- Reshape the data usin the `pivot_longer()` function
2- Creating factors and labels for the plot

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

MyTable <- data.frame(
  Pool = c(" ", "(CA) Domestic", "(CA) International", "(FR) International", "(US) Domestic", "(US) International" ), 
  ADomestic = c(0, 36000, 3000, 1200, 54000, 6000), 
  AInternational = c(0, 0, 600, 600, 0, 1200), 
  D_MTD = c(23.4, 0, 0, 0, 8.38, 0),
  I_MTD = c(6.63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)


to_plot <- MyTable %>%
  select(Pool, D_MTD, I_MTD) %>%
  # Data to long format
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains('MTD'), 
    names_to = 'pool_context', 
    values_to = 'used_minutes'
    ) %>%
  mutate(
    pool_context = factor(
        pool_context, c('D_MTD', 'I_MTD'), c('Domestic', 'International')
     ),
    # Labels only for non 0 values
    label = ifelse(used_minutes == 0, NA, used_minutes)
    )

to_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Pool, x = used_minutes)) +
  # Fill aesthetic only for bars, to avoid labels to get color too
  geom_col(aes(fill = pool_context)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  geom_label(aes(label = label), hjust = 1.1) +
  labs(fill = NULL, x = 'Used minutes (MTD)', y = 'Pool')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what you did with the table... I'm not understanding it completely, but for sure it works! I will  drill down on the functions you used, it's good learning! Thank you again!